# Custom NavigationBar in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm creating custom **navigationbar** in `swift` for every screen. I'm calling this function at `viewWillAppear` while first time loading it is coming properly if [First Time Loading Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7zta.png). I move to another screen it is changing. [Next View screen navigation title view is shifted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7zta.png). if I came back to previous screen then also it was shifted[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7zta.png). I'm unable to find the bug where code was wrong.left and right navigation items are placing fine . But **navigationtitle** view only getting shifting.

```
extension UIViewController {      
func reightMenuItems(_ isMenuBtn: Bool, _ navigationItem:UINavigationItem) {
    if isMenuBtn {
        let leftView = UIView()
        leftView.backgroundColor = .clear
        leftView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 44)
        let menuImage = UIImageView(image:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "MenuIcon"))
        menuImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        menuImage.frame = CGRect(x: 2.5, y: 6, width: 35, height: 32)
        leftView.addSubview(menuImage)



        let followButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        followButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 44)
        followButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -20, 0, 0)
        followButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnClickMenu), for: .touchUpInside)

        leftView.addSubview(followButton)
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(customView: leftView)]
    }else{
        let leftView = UIView()
        leftView.backgroundColor = .clear
        leftView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 44)

        let menuImage = UIImageView(image:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "arrow_white-left"))
        menuImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        menuImage.frame = CGRect(x: 12.5, y: 10.5, width: 15, height: 25)
        leftView.addSubview(menuImage)

        let followButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        followButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 44)

        leftView.addSubview(followButton)
        followButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnClickBack), for: .touchUpInside)
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(customView: leftView)]
    }
}

fileprivate func leftMenuItems(_ isCart: Bool, _ navigationItem: UINavigationItem) {
    //lecftButtons
    if isCart  {
        let reightView = UIView()
        reightView.backgroundColor = .clear
        reightView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 44)

        let menuImage = UIImageView(image:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Cart"))
        menuImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        menuImage.frame = CGRect(x: 2.5, y: 6, width: 35, height: 34)
        reightView.addSubview(menuImage)

        let cartBtn = UIButton(type: .system)
        cartBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 44)

        reightView.addSubview(cartBtn)
        cartBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnClickCart), for: .touchUpInside)
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(customView: reightView)]
    }else{
        let composeButton = BtnFontBold20()
        composeButton.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
        composeButton.titleLabel?.textColor = .white
        composeButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 00, width: 34, height: 44)
        composeButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 0)
        composeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnClickCart), for: .touchUpInside)
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(customView: composeButton)]
    }
}

func setupNavItems(_ navigationItem: UINavigationItem , day:String = "",address:String = "",type:Int,isMenuBtn:Bool,isCart:Bool,title:String = "") {

    //NavigationItem
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setValue(true, forKey: "hidesShadow")
    //Shadow
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.5, height: 1.5)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5

    //reight Menu Items
    reightMenuItems(isMenuBtn, navigationItem)
    leftMenuItems(isCart, navigationItem)

    let height = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0
    let leftButtonWidth: CGFloat = 90 // left padding
    let width2 = AppConstants.screenWidth - leftButtonWidth
    print(width2)
    let Titleview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width2, height: height))
      Titleview.backgroundColor = .clear
      navigationItem.titleView = Titleview
    if type == 1 {
        let dayLbl = FontBold18(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: min(width2/2,40), height: height))
         dayLbl.text = day
        dayLbl.textColor = .white
        dayLbl.textAlignment = .left
        dayLbl.numberOfLines = 1
        Titleview.addSubview(dayLbl)



        let DirectImag = UIImageView()
        DirectImag.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        DirectImag.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "RightDirection")
        Titleview.addSubview(DirectImag)
        DirectImag.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        DirectImag.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15).isActive = true
        DirectImag.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15).isActive = true
        DirectImag.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dayLbl.trailingAnchor, constant:5).isActive = true
        DirectImag.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dayLbl.centerYAnchor).isActive = true


        let dayBtn = UIButton(type: .system)
        dayBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnClickASAPType), for: .touchUpInside)
        Titleview.addSubview(dayBtn)
        dayBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        dayBtn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dayLbl.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        dayBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dayLbl.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        dayBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dayLbl.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        dayBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dayLbl.widthAnchor , constant:25).isActive = true



        let addLbl = FontBold18()
        addLbl.textColor = .white
        addLbl.textAlignment = .left
        addLbl.numberOfLines = 1
        Titleview.addSubview(addLbl)
        addLbl.text = address
        addLbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addLbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: DirectImag.trailingAnchor,constant:5).isActive = true
        addLbl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
        addLbl.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: Titleview.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        addLbl.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: (width2 - dayLbl.frame.width) * 0.9).isActive = true

        let downImag = UIImageView()
        downImag.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        downImag.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "down-arrow-white")
        Titleview.addSubview(downImag)
        downImag.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        downImag.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15).isActive = true
        downImag.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15).isActive = true
        downImag.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addLbl.trailingAnchor, constant:5).isActive = true
        downImag.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addLbl.centerYAnchor).isActive = true


        let addressBtn = UIButton(type: .system)
        addressBtn.backgroundColor = .clear
        addressBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnClickAddress), for: .touchUpInside)
        Titleview.addSubview(addressBtn)
        addressBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addressBtn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addLbl.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        addressBtn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addLbl.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        addressBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addLbl.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        addressBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addLbl.widthAnchor).isActive = true

    }
    else if type == 2{
        let dayLbl = FontBold18()
        dayLbl.text = title
        dayLbl.textColor = .white
        dayLbl.textAlignment = .center
        dayLbl.numberOfLines = 1
        Titleview.addSubview(dayLbl)
        dayLbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        dayLbl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: Titleview.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        dayLbl.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: Titleview.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }

}

@objc func btnClickASAPType()  {
    print("DayExt")
   // self.overriderFunc()
}
 @objc func btnClickAddress()  {
    print("AddressExt")
}
@objc  func btnClickCart()  {
    print("CartExt")
}
@objc func btnClickMenu()  {
    print("MenuExt")

}
@objc func btnClickBack()  {
    print("backExt")
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

}
```

calling setupNavigation Method in viewDidLoad

```
 self.setupNavItems( self.navigationItem, day:"Today", address:"Jayanagar 4th Block", type: 1,isMenuBtn: false,isCart: true)
```